# Is SharedPreferences necessary for all data?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new in Android.

I have a database like this.

[image]

I used SharedPreferences for remember user information.

However, there is a point that I do not understand. **When the user logins the application, do I need to save all Firebase data in SharedPreference for the application to remember the user?**

**Which type of datas save in SharedPreference? I just want, If a user logins the application, my application will remember the user and its checkboxes, comments, likes or something else.**

It might be a stupid question, but I am new in this. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `sharedPreferences` for this purpose. You can save `int`, `String`, `boolean`, `float`, `double`... in `sharedPreferences`.

You need to save user information in `sharedPreferences` on login.

Comment: for saving user information you dont need to create multiple shared preference to save each and every value, save the user details in json format and convert into string and  then save it in to a sharedprefrence

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to save values. Make a model and the using Gson save all the values in one string instead of saving seperately.